# Why is my Django form being rendered as an <class object> in Local vars?

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to know why my form is not rendering.  The `ValueError` error message I get says:
`Need more than one value to unpack`

I understand why it says this (because the form is a shown as class object `<points.forms.OffensiveScoringForm object at 0x10323fed0>`)

`forms.py`

```
    from django import forms
    from django.forms import widgets


    SCORING_YARDS = [str(x) for x in range(0,55,5)]
    TD_SCORING= [str(x) for x in range(0,11)]
    INTERCEPTIONS = [str(x) for x in range(-10,1)]
    RECEPTIONS = [str(x) for x in [0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1,1.5,2]]
    RECEIVING_YARDS = [str(x) for x in range(0,55,5)]

    class OffensiveScoringForm(forms.Form):
        yards_per_point_passing = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, choices=SCORING_YARDS)
        points_per_passing_td = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, choices=TD_SCORING)
        points_per_interception = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, choices=INTERCEPTIONS)
        points_per_reception = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, choices=RECEPTIONS)
        yard_per_point_receiving = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, choices=RECEIVING_YARDS)
        points_per_receiving_td = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, choices=TD_SCORING)
        yards_per_point = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, choices=SCORING_YARDS)
        rushing_td = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, choices=TD_SCORING)
```

Any help or insight as to why my form is not rendering would be appreciated, thank you for viewing. Here is my code:

`views.py`

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from myapp.forms import OffensiveScoringForm

    def home(request):
        form = OffensiveScoringForm()
        return render(request,'base.html',{
            'form':form,
        })
```

`base.html`

```
    <form action = "/nothing/" method="get">
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not form the value of choices that are being specified are not as expected.

Value for choices should be list of tuples. In tuple first item is actual value while 2nd is displayed text.

your code for defining values for `SCORING_YARDS` gives:

```
>>> [str(x) for x in range(0,55,5)]
['0', '5', '10', '15', '20', '25', '30', '35', '40', '45', '50']
```

Rather you may want is:

```
>>> [(x, str(x)) for x in range(0,55,5)]
[(0, '0'), (5, '5'), (10, '10'), (15, '15'), (20, '20'), (25, '25'), (30, '30'), (35, '35'), (40, '40'), (45, '45'), (50, '50')]
>>>
```

Similarly, you may want to fix for others.